# How do I save my Highest Time for each level on playerprefs?

Tags: unity, timer, savegame

So I want to make hill climb wanna be game but have an issue with saving `bestTime` each level, the point is I want to save the best time for each level to playerprefs also save it on text value in main menu like the image.

here my timer script :

```
 public void TimerSystemOn()
{
    if (timerIsRunning)
    {
        if (timeRemaining > 0)
        {
            timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
            DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
        }
        else
        {
            if (timeRemaining <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;

                if (!timerIsRunning)
                {
                    TimeOut();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!timerIsRunning)
    {
        ReachFinishLine();
        DisplayTime(timeRemaining);

    }
}

void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
{
    timeToDisplay += 1;

    float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
    float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Minutes", minutes);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Seconds", seconds);
    timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);

    float highscoreMins = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Minutes");
    float highscoreSec = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Seconds");

    if (minutes > highscoreMins || seconds > highscoreSec)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Minutes", minutes);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Seconds", seconds);
    }
    Debug.Log("HighscoreSec : " + highscoreSec);
}
```

that's my current script to save the bestTime. and this script call on the game, when died the timer value or `time remaining = 0` and when the car reached the destiny `timer will be stopped but the value saved to best time`
I confused here about saving that value and save it on each level

I want to save it in the bottom text.
[image]

Comment: No offence, but it's unclear what you need help with.  See [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited that @JimU

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is. Does this script not do what you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Philipp is that clear?

Comment: @YouCanCallMeSyarif There doesn't seem to be any code in your question which handles the case that the car reached the destination. You might want to do that first before you think about how to save the score in that case.

Comment: @Philipp I've added that again seems not saved because I already add that before.

Comment: That code is confusing. Apparently it only does something when the player reaches the finish line and is also dead at the same time?!?

Comment: yes, I make it a plot twist so when the car reaches the finish line and passes it the car or player is dead with an explosion.@Philipp

Comment: Can you please remove all the parts from your code which are irrelevant to the actual problem? You are making the question unclear when your code contains a lot of features which are unrelated. It's also possible that one of these unrelated features might actually cause a problem which prevents your solution from working.

Comment: Should the first PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Minutes", minutes); really save to playerprefs? I mean at the end you check with the condition if it is better than the highscore but you save the value regardless right away at the start of your function

Comment: @Zibelas no that Playerprefs on the displayTime methods not saving any. maybe i should save the time remaining instead of minutes and seconds am I right? if yes I confused about where i should call it?

Comment: Currently you save a time to playerprefs, load the same time again as a highscore and last you are checking if this time is a new highscore.

Comment: @Zibelas I already check that for the new highscore but not working, on this line`if (minutes > highscoreMins || seconds > highscoreSec)`, sorry maybe you can write the script down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically always saving the time as highscore. The comments are explaining why your current code is not doing what it should.

```
//Here you save already to your playerPref
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Minutes", minutes);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Seconds", seconds);
timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
//Here you load the same time that you just saved
float highscoreMins = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Minutes");
float highscoreSec = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Seconds");
//This condition does nothing since the time is the same value and we saved it already
if (minutes > highscoreMins || seconds > highscoreSec)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Minutes", minutes);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Seconds", seconds);
}
```

If you need a highscore per level, you might add a level prefix. And you can always save the time in total seconds since you even have the time already in seconds. For display purpose you convert it, for saving it is not needed. Keep it simple with one value.

You should as well not mix saving and displaying. Make an extra saving function that can determinate handles saving your highscore.

**(Your display method should as well not handle the increase of time, this is another part you should rework)**

```
void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay){
     timeToDisplay += 1;
     float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
     float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);   
     timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
}

void SaveIfHighScore(float time, string level){
     float currentHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Time_" + level);
     if (time > currentHighscore) {
         PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time_" + level, time)
     }
}
```

This assumes that highscore means the longer time, the better it is. If you need it to be fastest time, you need to switch the >.

Comment: where should i put Playerprefs.setFloat("Time_") is it on the start ?

Comment: You mean for the initial setting of the time for the very first time? Check if the key exists with HasKey Playerprefs.HasKey("Time_" + level), and if that is false, you can init the default highscore for certain levels